# Como acessar o arquivo styles.scss de dentro de um componente do Angular

Tags: angular, scss

Estou trabalhando com Angular (projeto gerado pelo `@angular/cli`), e a estrutura do meu projeto está abaixo:

```
src
 | - app
      | - foo
           | - foo.component.js
           | - foo.component.scss
           | - foo.component.html
 | - styles
      | - _variables.scss
```

No meu arquivo `foo.component.scss` eu estou tentando acessar o arquivo `_variables.scss` para pegar uma variavel que contém uma cor padrão para o projeto. Para fazer isso, estou utilizando a estrutura abaixo:

```
@import '~/.../src/styles/_variables.scss';

foo {
    background-color: $color-red;
}
```

Existe alguma forma mais simples de fazer a importação desse arquivo dentro de folhas de estilo dos componentes? ou criando uma referência nos arquivos de config, ou alguma outra configuração?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já definiu o projeto Angular como sass?

Você pode acessar a pasta do seu projeto, e digitar o seguinte comando.

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

Confira seu seu config está assim:

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "scss",
  "component": {
  }
}
```

Comment: eu acabei usando uma tag que achei no schema do arquivo `angular-cli.json` chamada `stylePreprocessorOptions`. com ela eu pude dizer aos projeto que a pasta `src/styles` é uma pasta padrão para acesso em qualquer componente. assim só preciso chamar o nome do arquivo que quero ali dentro...